# If/value issue?

Tags: java, if-statement

Simply put this program is merging two arrays containing coordinates into one larger array, the only issue is within my arrays there are lots of [0][0] values, I'm simply trying to count the number of coordinate pairs that are NOT 0 , 0

```
    counter = 0;

    int merged[][] = new int[lupper.length + llower.length][COLUMNS];


    for (int i=0; i<ROWS; i++){ 
        merged[i][0] = lupper[i][0];
        merged[i][1] = lupper[i][1];


        for (int j=lupper.length; j<ROWS; j++){ 
            merged[j][0] = llower[j][0];
            merged[j][1] = llower[j][1];
        }
    }

    for ( int i=0; i<merged.length; i++){
        if (merged[i][0] == merged[0][0]){
            counter = counter++;
        }
        if (merged[i][1] == merged[0][0]){
            counter = counter++;
        }
    }
```

Why does the counter returns as 0 continuously?

Comment: Main problem counter returns as 0 continously,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have in your code:

```
counter = counter++;
```

It *does not increment* the value of `counter`. You can instead try:

```
counter++;
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your counter is that it should say:

```
counter++;
```

and not:

```
counter = counter++;
```

The reason for this is that it will increase the value of the right hand counter after it has been evaluated. Thus will the old value of counter be assigned to the left hand side counter. This meaning that counter will always be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Your `llower` loop is wrong. It should not be nested in the `lupper` loop and the indexes are wrong. The following code does not loop at all because the length of `lupper` is equal to `ROWS`

```
   for (int j=lupper.length; j<ROWS; j++){ 
        merged[j][0] = llower[j][0];
        merged[j][1] = llower[j][1];
    }
```

Try this...

```
for (int i=0; i<ROWS; i++){ 
    merged[i][0] = lupper[i][0];
    merged[i][1] = lupper[i][1];
}


for (int j=0; j<ROWS; j++){ 
    merged[j+ROWS][0] = llower[j][0];
    merged[j+ROWS][1] = llower[j][1];
}
```

Also, as others have pointed out you need to change `counter = counter++` to `counter++`